# Возможно ли определить на каком api работает сайт?

Tags: парсер, api

Всем привет, есть сайт, нужно раскрыть его апи, так как парсинг сайта чрезвычайно сложен. Какой софт мне использовать?

Comment: почтовый клиент - пишете письмо владельцу и спрашиваете

Comment: @MikhailVaysman не факт, что у владельца есть документация.

Comment: Этот сайт является SPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Берёшь [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)
2. Если сайт использует https, включаешь в настройках фиддлера перехват и расшифровку https, подтверждаешь установку корневого сертификата
3. Открываешь сайт и смотришь, какие запросы он шлёт на требуемые действия
4. Из своего приложения посылаешь похожие запросы
5. Степень похожести смотришь в фиддлере, по необходимости используешь вкладку Composer, чтобы понять, каких именно заголовков тебе не хватает (берёшь оригинальный запрос и пытаешься удалять лишнее, либо добавлять к своему)

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если это крупный портал, то с большой вероятностью он имеет собственное апи, которое может и не раскрывать. Тогда задача его использования превращается в угадывание всех методов, что нереально.

Comment: Угадывание? А нельзя ли проследить за запросом?

Comment: Это и есть своеобразное угадывание. Но часть методов может получиться отследить путем мониторинга сетевой активности через консоль отладки. Но в этом случае вы не сможете однозначно узнать все методы и их спецификации. Может для вашей задачи этого и хватит.

Comment: Если у сайта есть приложение на телефоне, то по запросам от приложения можно понять api, но там будет сложно с https

Comment: @gil9red, Packet Capture на андроид поможет даже с SSL.

Comment: @qli9red, я как раз и делаю неофициальный клиент