# JavaScript вызов из C+/C#

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

Есть сайт, на сайте подключен скрипт

что нужно сделать, что бы на C++/C#, я имитировал непрерывное нахождение на сайте(пока программа запущена), то-бишь, что-бы этот js скрипт постоянно выполнялся.

Без использования WEBBROWSER!

Comment: Что значит Без использования WEBBROWSER?

Comment: то есть без использования элемента C# webbrowser

Comment: Используйте COM-объект эксплорера

Comment: можно чуть подробнее?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, зачем, если это то же самое, что webbrowser?

Comment: @Qwertiy эмуляция браузера без браузера подобна эмуляции с браузером, но без браузера.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов - обдумаю Ваш комментарий в ближайшие выходные

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос состоит из двух частей.

1. Что надо делать, чтобы сайт считал, что ты на нём находишься?
   Вот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/682629/178988
2. Как сделать такое же из своего приложения?
   Стоит глянуть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/730553/178988.
   Вот тут [большая тема](//bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=43360) о том, что может понадобиться при написании такого на .net.
   Если кратко, то надо создать свой CookieContainer, скаладывать в него все приходящие куки (при этом вручную обрабатывать редиректы, т. к. при автоматический обработке куки, выставленные в ответе с редиректом, потеряются) и добавдять этот контейнер ко всем отправляемым запросам.

Comment: у меня майнер на javascript, и он никаких куков не получает и не отправляет, так что это не поможет

Comment: Тогда запускай его на node.js, а не на шарпе.